# Facebook Graph API - Since date

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get a user's feed since a specific time (UNIX Timestamp) ?

For example I'd like to get the user's feed since `1364428800`

I can't find information on this on facebook, but I'd really appreciate an answer with a link to where this information is, instead of just an answer to the question :)

---

Forgot to say, I'm using PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here at facebook.stackoverflow , i can use `?since=<value>`

That `<value>` can be a time string or a timestamp, so it fits my needs!